# Reference data from another 'spreadsheet' in Google Docs/Drive

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way i can reference data from another Google Spreadsheet in Google Docs/Drive?

e.g., **spreadsheet-A, sheet 1, column A** is a dynamic reference of **spreadsheet-B, sheet 1, column E**

I'm not talking about copying and pasting the data, but referencing its values, in the same way that you could if you were using `=E:E` if they were in the same spreadsheet.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[You can import data from another spreadsheet using the `importrange()` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340):

```
=importrange(spreadsheet-key, range)
```

`spreadsheet-key` is part of the url of the spreadsheet that contains the data you want to import. It looks like "0AsaQpHJE_LShdFhSRWZBWWMxem1pZGxhWG1XZzlic0E". `range` defines the cells you want to import.

In your example, you would look for the `spreadsheet-key` in the URL of spreadsheet B, and then in spreadsheet A, cell A1, you would put:

```
=importrange("key-of-spreadsheet-b", "E:E")
```

Don't forget to surround the key and range with quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks, ive implemented a test here - [SPREADSHEET1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjhmNC-l_CS3dEt3czJSLXBvTDBoZXNwR0N4dlg2dHc#gid=0) & [SPREADSHEET2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjhmNC-l_CS3dGpqekV6M2hzV2ZnZzlrVUFPeS1ZcEE#gid=0) But if you make a change in sheet2 it dosnt seem to update in sheet1 any ideas why that might be ?

Comment: An update on my previous comment - the updates between the two sheets seem to be delayed

Comment: the delimiter is `;` not `,` as in `=importrange("key"; "Cell:Cell")`

Comment: @Rufinus That depends on your locale.

Comment: Just because it took me a minute to figure out, if there are multiple sheets in the target you reference them like this '=importrange("_spreadsheet-key_", "_Sheet-name_! _range_")'

Comment: @sam while a late reply, this should be for others that just see this answer. It could be related to `File > Spreadsheet settings... > Calculations > Recalculation`

Comment: You can actually use the whole URL, not just the "spreadsheet key".